# JavaScript if statement array code not working

Tags: jquery

I would like to optimize this code:

```
if (fd.field('Question_2').value.includes('Name') && fd.field('Question_2').value.includes('Address'))
```

Instead of typing up the same statement after &&, is it possible to put into one if statement?

Here is an example, the syntax isn't correct but something like this would be much better to type and save space in the JS editor..

```
if (fd.field('Question_2').value.includes = ['Name', 'Phone/Email Address'])
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: @NullDev That is an OR, not an AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
/**
 * hasEvery - Check if a string includes all the passed values in array
 * @param {String} str The string to search
 * @param {Array} arr The array with case-sensitive values to search in string
 * @return {Boolean} true if all values in array are found in string
 */
const hasEvery = (str, arr) => arr.every(v => str.includes(v));

const value = "foo Address bar Name baz";
console.log(hasEvery(value, ["Name", "Address"])); // true
console.log(hasEvery(value, ["Name", "Test"]));    // false
```

If you like to can also use rest parameters:

```js
/**
 * hasEvery - Check if a string includes all the passed values
 * @param {String} str The string to search
 * @params {...String} args Values to match
 * @return {Boolean} true if all values are found in string
 */
const hasEvery = (str, ...args) => args.every(v => str.includes(v));

const value = "foo Address bar Name baz";
console.log(hasEvery(value, "Name", "Address")); // true
console.log(hasEvery(value, "Name", "Test"));    // false
```

Comment: I don't get why this answer is downvoted, it's correct except you should probably point out that `value` in your answer is just `fd.field('Question_2').value` from the OP

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you could do is just use a variable instead of looking it up

```js
const q2Value = fd.field('Question_2').value.
if (q2Value.includes('Name') && q2Value.includes('Address')){}
```

Other option is using [reg exp using look aheads](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%3F%3D.*%5CbName%5Cb%29%28%3F%3D.*%5CbAddress%5Cb%29.*%24%2F)

```
const namAddyRegExp = /^(?=.*\bName\b)(?=.*\bAddress\b).*$/;
const str = "sfdsafdsf Name sdafdsf dsfdsf Address sdfsaf";
if(namAddyRegExp.test(str)){}
```

Comment: I like this solution of using RegExp and `\b` just to make sure the matches are delimited by a Word Boundary, which in my example that's not the case and `.includes()` could really easily give back false positives.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**:
Using regex:

```js
fd.field('Question_2').value.match(/(?=.*Name)(?=.*Address)/);
```

As long as you have only few strings to compare like `Name` and `Address`, it should be acceptable.

**old post:**

wrong solution, checking if *only one* of the string is in the value:

```js
fd.field('Question_2').value.match(/(Name|Address)/);
```

Comment: This is name OR address... It is not name AND address

Comment: Ah ok I was wondering why I was downvoted. Then you can use `/(?=.*Name)(?=.*Address)/` instead. Using `includes` in the question assumes that we are looking for a substring in a string